# How to load multiple ned source paths for opp_run command line execution

Tags: eclipse, omnet++, veins

I'm trying to run the .ini file from command line with opp_run

the ned source files paths are below (as what can be seen from gui)

Loading NED files from ..:  6
Loading NED files from ../../src:  8
Loading NED files from ../../../../../omnetpp-5.6.2/Mastersproject/inet/src:  831
Loading NED files from ../../../../../omnetpp-5.6.2/Mastersproject/inet/examples:  174
Loading NED files from ../../../../../omnetpp-5.6.2/Mastersproject/inet/tutorials:  10
Loading NED files from ../../../../../omnetpp-5.6.2/Mastersproject/inet/showcases:  46
Loading NED files from ../../../../../veins-master/veins-master/examples/veins:  1
Loading NED files from ../../../../../veins-master/veins-master/src/veins:  43

What should be my command from the linux terminal??
i'm in the project folder in the terminal and running the command

opp_run -u Cmdenv -n ../../src -f omnetpp.ini

The output is

```
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2019 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 5.6.2, build: 200518-aa79d0918f, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer

Setting up Cmdenv...

Loading NED files from ../../src:  8

<!> Error: The following NED types could not be fully resolved due to a missing base type or interface: vanettutorials.veins_inet.VeinsInetApplicationBase, vanettutorials.veins_inet.VeinsInetCar, vanettutorials.veins_inet.VeinsInetManager, vanettutorials.veins_inet.VeinsInetMobility, vanettutorials.veins_inet.VeinsInetRoutingCar, vanettutorials.veins_inet.VeinsInetSampleApplication

End.
```

How can i give multi ned source folders in the terminal?? so that it doesn't give this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-n` option. You can provide a colon separated list of NED directories.